# Does iBeacon Ranging work in a Today Extension?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ibeacon, ios8-extension

I am trying to range iBeacons in a Today Extension.

I do get a **didChangeAuthorizationStatus** message showing sufficient privileges from my **locationManager**. Good.

However any further **didRangeBeacons** messages/activity is missing.

I wonder if this is a Today Extension specific issue or if it has something to do my code – I put all my tracking code into a Cocoa Touch Framework and it does run well inside an active app in the foreground.

Has anybody had any luck ranging iBeacons in a Today Extension?

Comment: I have't tried it yet but as far as I know it **should** work. It's not forbidden API for extensions, for example.